# Why is the post-increment ++ more widely used over the pre-increment in programming examples?

Tags: coding-style

Seems like in most cases it would make more sense to use the pre yet somehow post is far more common.

```
while (counter < 10)
  counter++;
```

Comment: Why do you think post increment is far more common?

Comment: In my opinion `i++` reads more naturally than `++i` to indicate an increment (in the sense that it conveys the idea of the leftmost operand being the one assigned to as with normal assignment). Perhaps it is for this reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading everything I can find on the history of `++` and `--`, it seems that there is no technical reason for this convention, if it is even a convention (more on that later). Hence, I assume it must be an issue of a personal preference evolved. I'd posit that it has to do with readability. `counter++` could be seen as  more intuitive than `++counter` because it is an assignment operator. Essentially, it's shorthand for `counter = counter + 1`. Here you have the increment on the right being assigned to the left-hand expression. `counter++` naturally better fulfills this logic.

However, it is not necessarily a convention. [Some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30036749/is-it-still-better-to-prefer-pre-increment-over-post-increment) would argue that the prefix operator is always better (admittedly for mostly historical reasons). Personally, I prefer the prefix because it makes more sense to me in the context of other unary operators like `&`, `*`, etc. as well as the possible speed optimization.

Comment: code("counter = counter + 1") != code("i++")

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is there rebelious nature. "Who cares about speed?". ++i and i++ are just as easy to read. I didnt even concieve that persons would have a warm time understanding ++i. But where I am standing, there is no difficulty reading any of them. So I choose the one that has less overhead. It is not a big boost, but it is also not harder to type.